# No listening socket displayed

Tags: java, networking, netty

I'm writing a Java game server using Netty. I can successfully connect the client from localhost, but I cant from a remote PC. No listening socket is displayed in `netstat` util. Am I missing something in my conf?

```
@Override
public void startServer(String host, int port) {
    // Initialize server bootstrap
    if (bootstrap == null) {
        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(channelPipelineFactory);
        bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    }

    // Unbind the port if bound
    if (serverChannel != null && serverChannel.isBound()) {
        serverChannel.unbind();
    }
    serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(hostAddress);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `hostAddress`?

Comment: what error do you receive when trying to connect to the server from a remote PC?

Comment: You ask if something missing in your conf. Show the conf.

Comment: the value of the hostAddress was tried as "localhost" and "10.0.42.1" (ip address as the remote host)

Comment: when I'm trying to connect to the server from a remote PC I receive timeout exception, smth like that

Comment: Why do you pass in `host` and `port` to this method, when you completely ignore them and use `hostAddress` instead?

Comment: `host` and `port` are from the old api `hostAddress` is based on the properties passed to VM during launch 10.0.42.1 and 7777 in our case

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir The 'old API' is meaningless outside your workplace. The point is that your code doesn't do what it says it does. Possibly you are looking for the wrong port. There is no evidence here to the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding on the wildcard address, 0.0.0.0 (or ::0 for IPv6). The server will then listen all available interfaces.